# What are some design patterns for doing version control of an object?

Tags: design-patterns, version-control, event-sourcing, memento

What are some design patterns for keeping a history of an object as it changes.  I don't need anything as heavy duty as [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html), just the ability to save past versions  when a specific event happens (in this case when a print form button is pressed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could look for the  [memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_Pattern)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds isomorphic to tracking undo information.  The usual pattern for this is a variant of the Command pattern: you keep a queue in time order of previous states, with an operation to restore to the previous state.

Comment: The difference is that the history itself is persisted whereas with undo info you don't need anything of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at Martin Fowler's temporal patterns:  http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/timeNarrative.html